# Run a java website using mysql on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I test my website using Mysql database on my local pc, and I use tomcat for the server. Now I want to upload it to google app engine to let others view the website, is possible to do that, or maybe I need to change some configuration file? Or GAE using other storage solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run local MySQL instances on the AppEngine, you will need to used [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/)/

Answer (score 0):

you can't upload it. maybe you must make some changes, more than just config files changes. appengine have some limitations that you need read [appengine](https://developers.google.com/)
use eclipse plugin to check

Comment: Thank you, i looked at the document, JDBC DRIVER need to be changed, and some other thing.